# Sending an audio file (to headset) through Bluetooth in Android

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth, headset

Well I read many threads in Stack overflow about file transfer by bluetooth in android and they have mentioned that sending "any" file is same whether its a *.txt file or a song. But I am using a headset on which i want a music to play by bluetooth. It requires such protocols

Audio/video data transport protocol (AVDTP)
Used by the advanced audio distribution profile to stream music to stereo headsets over an L2CAP channel. Intended to be used by video distribution profile.
In the protocol stack, AVDTP is bound to L2CAP.

We have to use this protocol to stream the data. So I don't think any normal file transfer would work. Can some redirect me to tutorial wherin I can code for such an application or help me by any ways or link? 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Are you just trying to play music from the device to a bluetooth headset?

If so, you don't need to do anything to get it to play on the headset. Simply play the music as you normally would (with MediaPlayer or AudioTrack) and pair the bluetooth headset in android settings and it will play fine